# Remove first separator in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

I am using following code to get my menu.

My problem is Span is not getting added and I want to remove the first separator.

```
<div id="sub_nav">
<?php $menuParameters = array(
    'container'       => false,
    'echo'            => false,
    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'before'           => '<span id="separator"> | </span>'
); ?>
<?php echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' ); ?>
</div>
```

The output I got is:

```
<div id="sub_nav">
    | <a href=""> Fashion Insider</a>
    | <a href=""> Leasing</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you putting that entire piece of PHP in a template file or in functions.php?  Also, `strip_tags` is why you're not getting your span tags.  Its only set to allow `a` or anchor tags.  See answer below

Answer (score 2):

If all you're attempting to do is add a separator between links you'd be better off just scrapping what you have and do this:

Create a new menu in the WP backend.  Add your pages/links and save the menu.

Then just use `<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Name of Menu Here' )); ?>` to display your menu.  It will render an unordered list that you can then style using CSS

Use CSS to style the `<li>` tags that are rendered.  Give each one a left or right border to achieve your separators.  That will also not include an unnecessary span tag around each on to just ad a pipe separator.

Comment: This is the option I use all the time. Just as an FYI, it may be better to use `border-left` and `:first-child` since [Internet Explorer 8 Doesn't Support `:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F%3Alast-child#Browser_compatibility)